# Суммирование одинаковых полей

Tags: mysql, sql

Как изменить запрос так, что если название групп одинаковое, но цифры на конце разные(к примеру ПМ11 и ПМ12), то запрос бы подсчитывал для них общее значение лекций, семинаров и т.д.

```
SELECT
    `class`,
    `discipline`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_students`, 0)) AS `count_students`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лекция', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lection`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Семинар', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `seminar`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `laboratory`,
    SUM(`type`='Лекция') AS `groups`,
    SUM(`type`='Лабораторная') AS `subgroups`
FROM
    `list` WHERE course_semestr = '1-1'
GROUP BY
    `class`,
    `discipline`
```

Ссылка на запрос:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7afd8/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    if(instr(class, '1')=0, class, substr(class, 1, instr(class, '1')-1)) as class,
    `discipline`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_students`, 0)) AS `count_students`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лекция', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lection`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Семинар', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `seminar`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `laboratory`,
    SUM(`type`='Лекция') AS `groups`,
    SUM(`type`='Лабораторная') AS `subgroups`
FROM
    `list` WHERE course_semestr = '1-1'
GROUP BY
    if(instr(class, '1')=0, class, substr(class, 1, instr(class, '1')-1)),
    `discipline`
```

Можно так попробовать. Я предположил, что цифры могут быть только в конце и первая цифра всегда 1. Если это не так, придется наверное еще чуть чуть с регулярными выражениями поиграться